# any character deleting in y must appear in x

Tags: excel, function

There are two lists.One is blank and other contain values say a,b,c etc. When I delete a value in the list containing values a,b,c.. it must appear in other list which was blank. What is the formula for this in excel?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple excel function that allows a value to appear in another list when you press DELETE, you might be out of luck.  There are three ways I can think of that would allow you to pull off something like what you describe:

1. Write vba code that moves (or cut and pastes) the value to your other list.
2. Copy your original list to another (hidden) sheet.  Look up every value on this original list and compare it to your current list.  If the value doesn't show up, then display that value in your other blank list.
3. Just cut/paste it yourself from one list to another instead of deleting.